# PHP - MySQL Query, Show User Only Once

Tags: php, mysql

Good evening,

I am trying to alter some code from a user panel which includes user roles.  I would like certain roles to display the user for each role they're in, but certain roles I only want them shown once.

The MySQL table being used for this is:

```
id | username | password | displaygroup | usergroups
1  | User A   | Pass A   | 2            | 1,2,3
2  | User B   | Pass B   | 5            | 1,2,3,4,5
```

For example, if User A is in groups 1, 2 and 3, they should be listed three times for each group they're a part of.  Once a user is in a higher group, like User B, I only want them shown once, in their highest group.

The old queries that were being used were:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE displaygroup = '2' ORDER BY id");
while ($array = $db->assoc($query)) {
  echo $array['username'];
}
```

With that query, User A would only show once.

I have tried the following:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id");
while ($array = $db->assoc($query)) {
  $role = explode(',', $array['usergroups']);
  foreach ($role as $value) {
    if ($value == 1) {
      echo $array['username'];
    }
    if ($value == 2) {
      echo $array['username'];
    }
  }
}
```

With the above, it works perfectly fine for User A, as it shows them for groups 1, 2 and 3 that they're in.

However, User B is now showing up, since they are also in those roles.

How can I get it so User A continues to show for groups 1, 2 and 3, and User B only shows for group 5?

**UPDATE**

There seems to be confusion in my question.  I pretty much want it to do:

**Group 1**
User A

**Group 2**
User A

**Group 3**
User A

**Group 4**

**Group 5**
User B

Comment: Can you explain again, how user B will be shown once and not 5 times?

Comment: Hi Umashankar, I want it so if a user is in a group higher than 3, it only lists them once for their highest group, in this case User B being 5.  I don't want User B listed under groups 1, 2, 3 or 4.  If a user is in a group lower than 4, I want them listed each time, in this case User A being 1, 2 and 3.  I want User A to be listed under groups 1, 2 and 3, but not 4 and 5.

Comment: You say in your question, " but certain roles I only want them shown once". What specific roles are they only supposed to show one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reverse the `role` array and check from the last value. If higher value like `5` exist do your operation and break the loop.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id");
while ($array = $db->assoc($query)) {
  $role = explode(',', $array['usergroups']);
  $role = array_reverse($role);
  foreach ($role as $value) {
    if($value == 5) {
        echo $array['username'];
        break;
    }
    if ($value == 1) {
      echo $array['username'];
    }
    if ($value == 2) {
      echo $array['username'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Works like a charm.